# Hide/Unhide Excel Tab Ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, hide, show, ribbon

I really need help, sorry if this question has been already asked.

I have a addin installed on my computer for Excel, which creates a new Ribbon Tab, named "Forecast". This tab is useful only for a specific file, and for the other Excels I want it to be hidden.

I've been thinking on this a lot, and I came to the conclusion that the tab has to be hidden by default and shown by VBA code on opening of the file and hidden on beforeClose event, but I don't really know how to do this.

If anyone else has a better idea and would like to help me, I am very thankful.

Thank you

Comment: Possible to do it that way, but probably better to just put the ribbon tab in the file itself, rather than an Add-In. That would arguably be easier.

Comment: Ribbon Tab is an Add-In because we want to protect the code the buttons from tab are running. I thought it would be an easy command such as Application.Ribbon("Forecast").Visible = False, but I can't find the solution. Can you help me ?

Comment: Add-ins are no less accessible to the end user, unless you're distributing them in some other language compiled. An XLAM is still something the user can view and interact with, if s/he wants to.

Comment: The ribbon cannot really be manipulated by VBA alone. You need to modify the XML of the ribbon. It's rather complicated, and impossible for me to assist without seeing your existing XML and VBA callbacks.

Comment: @DavidZemens, my Add in is distributed as a setup, the code is written in C#. The user can't access the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no properties which available via the object model. The Ribbon UI is a static thing, to get any dynamism you need to use callbacks defined in the XML markup.

To get the job done you need to use the **getVisible** attribute for the tab control. When a document is opened/closed you can check out whether the tab should be displayed or not. If required, you can call the [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol(v=office.14).aspx) methods of the [IRibbonUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869817.aspx) interface to force the application to call your callbacks anew. Thus, you can show or hide a tab dynamically.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)